# pypi remote repository fails SSL Test

Tags: artifactory

It appears sometime in June of this year our SSL validation inside of Artifactory started to fail for https://files.pythonhosted.org. As a result we are no longer able to resolve remote lookups for python packages not hosted locally.

The error when I click `Test` on the remote repository settings page with `https://files.pythonhosted.org` as the hostname:

> Connection to remote repository failed: Certificate for doesn't match
> any of the subject alternative names:
> [r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net]

When I try to validate the SSL using openssl on the host linux server:

> openssl s_client -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443
> subject=/CN=r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net

If I pass the servername flag to openssl it finds the right cert:

> openssl s_client -servername files.pythonhosted.org -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443
> subject=/CN=*.pythonhosted.org

How do I go about fixing this in the UI?
server: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
artifactory version: EnterpriseX license 7.3.2 rev 70302900
[image: pypy remote settings]

**EDIT**
Appears this is most likely caused by the version of artifactory this specific instance is running. I was able to check a newer version than what this instance is running and it works correctly.

**EDIT2**
The system.yaml contained the following

> extraJavaOpts: -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
> this was disabling artifactory from resolving SNI enabled domains. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the reported scenario. Executing an openssl command to retrieve the certificate from the Python registry is returning certificates with a different CN apart from the expected one.

Command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443 </dev/null
```

I couldn't confirm if this is an issue with a redirect. However, executing the command to retrieve the certificate with server name in specific appears to be revealing the actual certificate for the remote site.
So, Could you please try using the following command, collect the certificate and use this certificate to replace the already amended certificates in support of this remote connection?

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443 -servername files.pythonhosted.org </dev/null
```

Comment: I did add the certificate using that command (matched what they had in their tutorial) https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-self-signed-certificate-to-artifactory-video/. And I can see in the logs it adding the crt file to the keystore of the service, but still gives me the same error sadly.
And based off the error 'that it doesn't match any subject alt names' I don't think adding the cert will help in this case. Its not matching up the hostname I'm giving it to the cert

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the artifactory you mentioned. But I can give you a hint on the certificate part, in general, your issue is caused by the website files.pythonhosted.org support SNI and your client-side cannot recognize the SNI support.

To check the server website ssl information, you can visit:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=files.pythonhosted.org&s=151.101.1.63

In the result, you can see a line "Certificate #2: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA) **No SNI**" which means there are 2 certificates in the server, and for more explanation, you can check
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360055289933-Why-is-SSLLabs-Certificate-2-RSA-2048-bits-SHA256withRSA-No-SNI-test-showing-an-error-

And OpenSSL older version cannot handle SNI correctly as well, that's why your openssl command is not returning the expected result. Actually, the same command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443
```

with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips on Oracle Linux 7, it returns:
`r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net`

with OpenSSL 1.1.1 FIPS on Centos 8, it returns: `*.pythonhosted.org`

So the issue may be related to https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-556
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/BI-167/BI-167.html

Comment: Nice find on those jira issues. I'm on version 7.3.2 and the versions mentioned in those tickets is a lot older. Poking around the install folders I see httpclient versions of  
artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.5.10.jar  
artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.11.jar
Whichs puts me above their suggest version of 4.3.2

Comment: At this point I was able to get access to a artifactory install that was version 7.18, and it works, so I guess its just an old enough version of artifactory that it doesn't support SNI correctly

Comment: Glad to know, and I'm confused you are not accepting my answer and not even vote it up, it takes me quite some time to test your specific situation.