# "Could not install packages due to an OSError" while trying to download python packages

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate, pypi, oserror

I've been using python v3.12 for the past month without any problem, but now out of nowhere i'm unable to download any packages at all. It gives this long list of warnings and an error.

```
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'"))': /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'"))': /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'"))': /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'"))': /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'"))': /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
> WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certificate: {'subject': ((('commonName', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),),), 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'BE'),), (('organizationName', 'GlobalSign nv-sa'),), (('commonName', 'GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2023 Q1'),)), 'version': 3, 'serialNumber': '01D06257899F0DD2481ECE65A0533F7E', 'notBefore': 'Apr 10 04:55:11 2023 GMT', 'notAfter': 'May 11 04:55:10 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'),), 'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1',), 'caIssuers': ('http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crt',), 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.globalsign.com/ca/gsatlasr3dvtlsca2023q1.crl',)}
> 
> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doesn't match 'r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net'")))
```

I looked and tried every solution I found on the internet, but none worked for me.
And I couldn't access https://files.pythonhosted.org/ from the browser either. It shows "Your connection is not private" error and says the connection is not secured. But it's only my laptop that is showing this error, so i think it's not a network problem?
[image]

Comment: Looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547533/pypi-remote-repository-fails-ssl-test Do you have any software on your device that intercepts connections, e.g. new or updated antivirus software?

Comment: I can connect https://files.pythonhosted.org/  and it has a valid certificate.

Comment: @Ry- No, I have no anti-virus software. I even disabled the Windows one and tried again, but it's not working.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Yes, it works fine on other devices. Just mine shows this error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and found that an entry in the `hosts` file for `pythonhosted.org` was causing the 'Misdirected Request' error. Here's how I resolved it:

1. **Open the Hosts File**:

   - **On Windows**: Run Notepad as an administrator, then open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
   - **On macOS/Linux**: Open Terminal and use `sudo nano /etc/hosts` or a similar command to edit the file with administrative privileges.
2. **Modify the Hosts File**: Search for entries with `pythonhosted.org`. Either delete these lines or comment them out by adding `#` at the beginning of each line.
3. **Save and Restart**:

   - **In Windows Notepad**: Save the changes by clicking File -> Save.
   - **In macOS/Linux Nano Editor**: Press `Ctrl + O` to write the changes, then `Ctrl + X` to exit.
   - Restart your computer.
4. **Test Your Access**: Try accessing https://files.pythonhosted.org/ again.

Comment: I'm not great at English, so I asked an AI to help me rephrase my answer. I had this problem today, and I fixed it by following these instructions.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution for a week now. And this worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: Worked like a charm, after a lot of frustration.. The only thing is I didn't need to restart the computer.

Comment: @psps: How did (all of) you end up with pythonhosted.org in your hosts file? Was adding it in the first place a commonly suggested fix to some other problem?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424036/11107541

Comment: @Ry- I believe so. I remember I had an issue while modifying my conda environment to install packages from Interactive Broker's Trader Workstation API several months ago. I forgot I changed the hosts file and am now here at this post with the same problem.

Comment: What is the reason behind the error though?